# jQuery ComboGrid auto select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My question is, How do I disable the autoselect feature in combo grid. The use case scenario is like this. I have a list of projects and I want combogrid to autocomplete the project name for me when I type it in. And that works great, perfect even. But the problem arises when I have a new project name "Underhill Parking Phase 2" and there is also a project name in the combogrid drop down that matches "Underhill Parking Phase 1". Since combogrid auto selects the list item when only one option is available. When I press tab or enter combogrid replaces "Underhill Parking Phase 2" with "Underhill Parking Phase 1". How can I disable this behavior? And since I have a hidden field that is populated when an item is selected if you fix the form visually you still get the wrong item posted in the hidden field.

Also the autoChoose and autoFocus options do not do what I am asking.

Comment: Do you have an example where check it?

Comment: How is this CodeIgniter related?